# Cache user-specific information such as mailbox in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.1

In Cakephp, is it possible to cache user-specific information such as mailbox and re-set the cache if there is a new mail.

Maybe in the browser cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont quite understand what you want to do?
if you want to cache userspecific und the user is logged in you can just append the UID to the cache path - this way it is only for this user.

```
$userSpecificCacheFile = 'my_file_name' . $uid;
```